# Mongoose function to typecast attributes to match Schema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

When using `Model.find(match)`, attributes are automatically typecast to field types as defined in the `Schema`.

This is especially useful for booleans and numbers when filters are specified from a query string, because query string parameters are always of `String` type.

Is this function exposed?

Rationale: Schema typecasting does not happen on the `Model.aggregate().match()` stage, because as soon as aggregation is started, the pipeline officially no longer has a Schema (although theoretically the first stage is identical to a normal find).

For reasons, I want to do something like the following:

```
match = mongoose.applySchemaTypecasting(match, schema)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to do it will be to just create a new temporary document on every new request which will automatically typecast all the fields according to schema.
For eg:-

```
const doc = new Model(match);
```

You can then run document.validate to get a promise to determine whether it was a match or not.

```
doc.validate(function (err) {
 if (err) handleError(err);
 else // validation passed
});
```

And then you can simply avoid saving doc in the database.

Also, after looking into the source code for mongoose, I have noticed that mongoose does typecasting separately for different fields and not for the whole document. So there might not be a function for that available through api to do that for a whole document.

However, you can use SchemaType.cast() exposed by mongoose to that that for individual fields.
Here is the link to documentation:- 
[Mongoose SchemaTypecast](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-cast)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with _"mongoose does typecasting separately for different fields and not for the whole document"_ and perhaps link towards the code on the github page?

Comment: Basically there is no exposed function where you can put a whole document and related schema and all the fields will be typecasted according to the schema. But mongoose does have separate typecast functions for each data type. Take a look at this https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/tree/master/lib/cast